# Firebird не использует индекс для primary key при запросе

Tags: sql, firebird

Нужно выбрать максимальное значение первичного ключа (id).

Делаю запрос:

```
select id
from peoples
order by id desc
rows 1;
```

получаю план запроса: `PLAN SORT ((PEOPLES NATURAL))`

тот же запрос но сортировка прямая:

```
select id
from peoples
order by id
rows 1;
```

получаю план запроса: `PLAN (PEOPLES ORDER RDB$PRIMARY43)`

Как заставить Firebird 2.5 использовать индекс при обратной сортировке?

ЗЫ: если создать дополнительный индекс по `id`, то при запросе этот свежесозданный индекс используется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, без дополнительного индекса никак. Из документации:

По сравнению с другими СУБД у индексов в Firebird есть еще одна особенность – сканирование индекса всегда однонаправленное, от меньших ключей к большим. Часто из-за этого индекс называют однонаправленным и говорят, что в его узле есть указатели только на следующий узел и нет указателя на предыдущий. 
...

Данная особенность приводит к невозможности использования ASC-индекса для DESC-сортировки или вычисления MAX и наоборот, невозможности использования DESC-индекса для ASC-сортировки или вычисления MIN.

Comment: Спасибо. Это плохо.